How can I access the latest data using the arXiv API?
I am currently developing a program that uses the arXiv API to retrieve a list of titles and abstracts of papers submitted on a given day.
In other words, it is a program that automatically retrieves the list of articles that can be accessed from the “new” link on the arXiv top page.
However, even if I perform a query search using the arXiv API according to the arXiv schedule(https://info.arxiv.org/help/availability.html), not a single result is returned.
For example, when I used Python to search using the following query at around 4:30am on September 25th 2024 (EDT), no articles were found.
import arxiv
client = arxiv.Client()
# The time in the query is in UTC.
querydata = "( cat:gr-qc ) AND ( lastUpdatedDate:[202409231800 TO 202409241800] )"
search = arxiv.Search(query = querydata, sort_by=arxiv.SortCriterion.LastUpdatedDate)
results = client.results(search)
i = 1
for r in results:
    print(str(i)+":"+r.title)
    i = i + 1
# code fixed at around 9:00pm on September 25th 2024(EDT)

According to the schedule published by arXiv, if I search using this query at this time, I should get results for papers submitted between 2:00 p.m. on Monday, September 23 and 2:00 p.m. on Tuesday, September 24. But that didn't happen.
Why is that? And how can I access the latest paper data using the arXiv API?
Please tell me.

Based on the documentation you are using the API wrong.
For search query as mentioned in the documentation https://info.arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual.html#query_details you can have only the mentioned prefix but in your code, you are using lastUpdatedDate in the query string, which is resulting in no answers, try removing it from the querydata you should see some results.
You can sort the list based on the last update date as mentioned in section 3.1.1.3 of https://info.arxiv.org/help/api/user-manual.html#search_query_and_id_list
please try and let us know the results to further help you out

Akhil, thank you for your reply.
However, even with this query, if I change the date, it will return the results i want.
So I think the problem is not with that part, but there may be another cause. What do you think?

Is it possible that there are no articles published?

I don't think so.Because if you look at the "new" link on the top page of arXiv(https://arxiv.org/list/gr-qc/new), you will see that many papers have been published.
